# Is AEoid compatible with Python 2.7 multithreading?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I've noticed the use of globals (`global` and `os.environ`) in [AEoid](https://github.com/Arachnid/aeoid).

Am I correct in assuming it will not work safely on App Engine using Python 2.7 with `threadsafe = true`?

If I am, is there some documentation that would help me in making it threadsafe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the current user is stored in a global, AEOid isn't currently threadsafe. This would be easy to fix, but AEOid has been deprecated for a long time, in favor of the [official OpenID authentication support](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/overview.html#Authentication_Options), there's probably no point fixing it (or using AEOid in the first place).

Comment: For me, AEoid is better.  Official OpenID authentication switches everything to OpenID, which I don't like.  Also, I'm using the PAPE extension right now, which is not supported.  I'll try getting rid of the global dependencies.